# Why doesn't this simple VBA code work in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to programming with VBA (or any language, let's be honest). I'm trying to do a project for work, adding short sections at a time to see if the code still works, and trying out new code in a separate Sub. I've come across an error that I can't get around. The results don't change when they're the only line in a separate Sub.

The following code works:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Student info")
```

Whereas the following code, when run, breaks with a 424 run-time error (object required). I've tried selecting instead of naming, still no luck. It does successfully copy the worksheet to the correct place, despite the error, but is called 'Template (2)'.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Student info")).name = "newname"
```

This is very confusing because the code below *does* work. Is it just that trying to name something after using 'add' *does* work, but after 'copy', it doesn't?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Student info")).name = Student_name
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The Worksheets.Add method returns a Worksheet object; Worksheet.Copy returns a boolean value.

Comment: @Zer0Kelvin Just for the sake of correctness `.Copy` is a sub and returns nothing

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Just for the sake of fairness: Copy is not a Sub, it is a method of the Worksheet object (you should know the difference) and it returns a boolean. Try to run

MsgBox Sheets (1) .Copy (after: = Sheets (Sheets.Count))

Comment: @Zer0Kelvin seems you are right, but [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) and object browser define it as sub.

Answer (score 1):

The reference (to the created copy) as return value (of a function) would be useful, but as [Worksheet.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) is a method of one worksheet (in opposite to [Worksheets.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add) what is a method of the worksheet**s**-collection), they didn't created it. But as you know where you created it (before or after the worksheet you specified in arguments, if you did), you can get its reference by that position (before or after).

In a function returning the reference:

```vb
Public Enum WorkdheetInsertPosition
    InsertAfter
    InsertBefore
End Enum

Public Function CopyAndRenameWorksheet(ByRef sourceWs As Worksheet, ByRef targetPosWs As Worksheet, ByVal insertPos As WorkdheetInsertPosition, ByVal NewName As String) As Worksheet
    'If isWsNameInUse(NewName) then 'Function isWsNameInUse needs to be created to check name!
        'Debug.Print NewName & " alredy in use"
        'Exit Function
    'End If

    With sourceWs
        Dim n As Long
            Select Case insertPos
                Case InsertAfter
                    .Copy After:=targetPosWs
                    n = 1
                Case InsertBefore
                    .Copy Before:=targetPosWs
                    n = -1
                Case Else
                    'should not happen unless enum is extended
            End Select
    End With

    Dim NewWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set NewWorksheet = targetPosWs.Parent.Worksheets(targetPosWs.Index + n) 'Worksheet.Parent returns the Workbook reference to targetPosWs
    NewWorksheet.Name = NewName ' if name already in use an error occurs, should be tested before
    Set CopyWorksheetAndRename = NewWorksheet
End Function
```

usage (insert after):

```vb
Private Sub testCopyWorkSheet()
    Debug.Print CopyAndRenameWorksheet(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template"), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Student info"), InsertAfter, Student_name).Name
End Sub
```

to insert the copy before the target worksheet, change third argument to `InsertBefore` (enumeration of options).
New `Worksheet.Name` needs to be unique or you'll get an error (as long you not implemented the `isWsNameInUse` function to check that).

Also note that there is a difference between [.Sheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets) and [.Worksheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets)

You can get the links to the documentation by moving the cursor (with mouse left-click) in the code over the object/method you want more infos on and then press <kbd>F1</kbd>